# Inherited interfaces being collected via @Autowired(required = false) in Spring

Tags: spring

I have two interfaces A and B. Interface B extends Interface A. Both of them implement a method getId() for identifying the implementations.

```
public interface A{
Long getId();
}

public interface B extends A {
Long getId();
}
```

I have multiple implementations for A and B both all over the software.

I have a method in spring for object collection of A and B both mentioned below:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
public void collectAImplementations(List<A> implementations) {
Map<Long, A> aMap = new HashMap<>(implementations.size());
for (A a : implementations) {
    aMap.put(a.getId(), a);
 }
}

@Autowired(required = false)
public void collectBImplementations(List<B> implementations) {
Map<Long, B> bMap =  new HashMap<>(implementations.size());
for (B B : implementations) {
   bMap.put(b.getId(), b);
 }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting implementations of both A and B in the aMap. Is there any way in Spring to get only A implementations in the AMap. One of the hack is to do an explicit check for B implementations in the collectAImplementations method. But is there any other solution?

Comment: B is A so it basically does what you would expect. Else don't make B extend A.

Comment: I know that but the problem is that functionally B has to extend A. Therefore I am looking for an alternative solution :)

Comment: The only solution is to filter... Spring will inject all beans o type a. As B is A it will be in that list.